# What is the best way to keep sockets secure after updates to either Docker for Mac with Kubernetes or Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, auto-update, minikube, docker-for-mac

I would like to develop a playbook rule for addressing how to manage socket securing for Docker and Kubernetes from either the standpoint of Docker For Mac or MiniKube- after auto-updates to any of the pieces of the puzzle. Maybe we need to throw out there the LLVM or (VM in question if we say use Virtual Box *and* a particular Unix/Linux flavor. Then we may also need look at enforcing SELinux or AppArmor or Seccomp. I just want to see where this rabbit hole may end us up in today, 2019-09-25, as I just embarked on the Kubernetes quest with minishift, co, and micro-services architecture with RHEL (I may sway away from the OS image to Alpine or something someone may suggest as a suitable alternative). The goal here is to provide support to a team from a system administration point of view, potentially from the stance of calming some long lived traditional experience in the world concerns with real manageable solutions to infrastructure migrations for larger business.

RHEL D0092 course work. Months of reading documentation with Docker and watching the past four updates on my development machine go by without a workable solution, knowing the inevitability was to get a Kubernetes cluster going after chewing on Kerrisk's bible for a while on the subject matter- Datagrams and Stream sockets and the like (and how people like to port it well for their individual use cases). I'm a novice system admin here, don't let me fool you. I just am not afraid to ride the big waves, that's all.

```sh
kubectl --namespace=kubedemo set image deployment/myvertex myvertex=burr/myvertx:v2
```

or

```py
import subprocess
import sys
import os

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    name = sys.argv[1]
else:
    # fd = input(the_path_passed_stdin)
    name = input("Update path/name for docker build:")

# test this with a "dryrun" first, you don't need a bunch of image clutter or control -c's
# No such file or directory trace means we need to call docker directly
proc = subprocess.run([f"error_test docker build -it {name} ."], encoding='utf-8', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Just a thought on automation of a playbook rule in some type of sequential fashion- in python if I can get suggestions, but bash is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes works over an HTTP API and normal IP sockets, not a local domain socket. So there isn't really anything to lock down. DfM's control socket is already tightly locked down to the active GUI user because DfM runs inside a Mac app container (totally different use of the term "container"). Basically there isn't anything you need to do, it's already as safe as it's getting.

Comment: And what becomes of Minikube? Also HTTP API and IP sockets through a VM of choice?

Comment: Minikube doesn't expose docker locally by default. It does allow remote usage of its docker socket with creds that are secured to the user, but that's fine.

Comment: From [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/) it states "Docker runs through a non-networked UNIX socket. It can also optionally communicate using an HTTP socket." I am now focusing on Kuberenetes reading. I was hoping to gain insight on alternatives to handling the .pem files and any wellknown ramifications of modifying $HOST:2376 (docs said it *should* run on port 2376), options to CSR, other ways to deal with client and .docker files- just a general idea on what people may use for their setups.

Comment: I don't really understand your question but I'm 99.999% sure you are overthinking this. There is nothing you need to do.

Comment: Sometimes being a little on the paranoid side is good practice... Thanks for the reassurances.